# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log \left( 1+x^{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)}{1+x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426325/evaluate-int-01-frac-log-left-1x2-sqrt3-right1x-mathrm-dx) and noted that it was posted back in 2013. Just tried V11.3 and got no analytic solution.

Just wondering if there is a way for Mathematica to give the **desired** result?

Machine VS Human

```
Integrate[Log[1 + x^(2 + Sqrt[3])]/(1 + x), {x, 0, 1}]
```

The closed form should be

$\qquad \frac{\pi^2}{12}\left( 1-\sqrt{3}\right)+\log(2) \log \left(1+\sqrt{3} \right)$

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake? Where is this integral applied?